# Monitor a running app in android

Tags: android, service, monitoring, process-monitoring

I am trying to make a kiosk type app for an android device, and I want to ensure that the app is always running, and restart it if it falls over.

My initial thought was to create a Service, pinned to the foreground, which periodically checks (using the system `Handler`) to see if the Activity (the main App with the UI) is running. If it isn't running, then the Service should restart the Activity by launching an intent using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.blah.blah.MyApp"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to see if a specific app is running or not?
And for bonus internet-points - could I tell if that app is in the foreground (and use the Service to keep the Activity in the foreground)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current Application(any application) package name running at the top
`String packageName= getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE).getRunningTasks(1).get(0)).topActivity.getPackageName();`

Run this code in your background service in a loop and checks for your application.

Comment: Great, thanks!

For others looking for this solution, I had to typecast @sachy's code thusly:
`String packageName= ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();`
It also requires:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`